# Workflow of celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am a beginner with django, I have celery installed.

I am confused about the working of the celery, if the queued works are handled synchronously or asynchronously. Can other works be queued when the queued work is already being processed?

Answer (score 2):

Celery is a task queuing system, that is backed by a message queuing system, Celery allows you to invoke tasks asynchronously, in a way that won't block your process for the task to finish, you can wait for the task to finish using the [`AsyncResult.get`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get).

Other tasks can be queued while a task is being processed, and if Celery is running more than one process/thread (which is the default case), tasks will be executed in parallel to each others.

It is your responsibility to make sure that related tasks are executed in the correct order, e.g. if the output of a task `A` is an input to the other task `B` then you should make sure that you get the result from task `A` before you start the task `B`.

Read [Avoid launching synchronous subtasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) from Celery documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're possibly a bit confused about what Celery does.

Celery isn't really responsible for queueing at all. That is taken care of by the queue itself - RabbitMQ, Redis, or whatever. The only way Celery gets involved at this end is as a library that you call inside your app to serialize to task into something suitable for putting onto the queue. Since that is done by your web app, it is exactly as synchronous or asynchronous as your app itself: usually, in production, you'd have multiple processes running your site, each of those could put things onto the queue simultaneously, but each queueing action is done in-process.

The main point of Celery is the separate worker processes. This is where the asynchronous bit comes from: the workers run completely separately from your web app, and pick tasks off the queue as necessary. They are not at all involved in the process of putting tasks onto the queue in the first place.